# Changing Font size in Disqus 2012

Tags: html, css, fonts, disqus

I am using Disqus 2012 commenting system on my website. My website default font is 13px (defined in the body tag), but the Disqus is displaying the comments with 14px. Is there anyway to change the font size in it?
I have tried a lot to check the HTML source of the comments with Firebug and specified the font size in my stylesheet but it does not work.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this functionality isn't currently available in Disqus 2012, Disqus is looking into additional customization options to help out in the future.